# Highlight sub array of tikzpicture generate array

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrays

In the generated 28 x 28 array of circles from the given code, I wanted to be able to highlight a specific sub array and have the respective arrows pointing out as follows:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
        \foreach \d in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
        \draw (.25 * \d - 2, -0.25 * \n + 2) circle (0.1cm);}}
        \draw (8, -0.25 * 14 + 2) circle (0.1cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option but by brute force, using shaped nodes, with their respective names to locate certain specific points using the calc library. Then, according to taste, I change the way that the arrows are connected, you can replace `to [out = angle, in = angle]` with `--` fi you need straight lines.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass [tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
        \foreach \d in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
            \node[draw,circle,black!30,inner sep=0.75mm](X\d-Y\n) at (.25 * \d - 2, -0.25 * \n + 2){};
        }
    }
    \draw
    ($(X28-Y14)!0.5!(X28-Y15)$)++(2cm,0)
        node[draw,circle,black,inner sep=0.75mm](out){};
    \foreach \n in {1, 2, ..., 6} {
        \foreach \d in {1, 2, ..., 6} {
            \draw
            (X20-Y11)+(.25 * \d,-0.25 * \n)node[draw,circle,black,inner sep=0.75mm](x\d-y\n){};
            \draw[-{Triangle[angle=45:.1cm 1]}]
            (x\d-y\n) to [in=180, out=0] (out);
        }
    }
    \draw
    ($(X14-Y1)!0.5!(X15-Y1)$)++(0,0.5cm)
        node[]{input neurons}
    (out)++(0,0.5cm)
        node[]{hidden neuron};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**ADDENDUM:**

---

You can add additional counters so that they can start from 0, in order to have nodes named from 0. In the first example there is no node with names from 0 since your counters start from 1. I added an additional example and some command definition notes.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass [tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment cfg
        >={Triangle[angle=45:.1cm 1]} % Arrows style by arrows.meta options
    ]
    \foreach \n [count=\y from 0] in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
        \foreach \d [count=\x from 0]in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
            \node[draw,circle,black!30,inner sep=0.75mm](X\x-Y\y) at (.25 * \d - 2, -0.25 * \n + 2){};
            %\node[node style options](node_name[char_variable]) at (node position[number,number]){node_text}; % Description of node definition args.
        }
    }
    \draw
    ($(X27-Y14)!0.5!(X27-Y14)$)++(2cm,0)
        node[draw,circle,black,inner sep=0.75mm](out){};
    %\draw (starting coordinate given by calc the middle point between nodes (Xa-Yb) and (Xc-Yd))
    %   node[node style options](node_name){node_text};
    \foreach \n [count=\y from 0] in {1, 2, ..., 6} {
        \foreach \d [count=\x from 0] in {1, 2, ..., 6} {
            \draw
            (X19-Y10)+(.25 * \x,-0.25 * \y)node[draw,circle,black,inner sep=0.75mm](x\x-y\y){};
            \draw[->]
            (x\x-y\y) to [in=180, out=0] (out);
        }
    }
    \draw
    ($(X14-Y0)!0.5!(X14-Y0)$)++(0,0.5cm)
        node[]{input neurons}
    (out)++(0,-0.5cm)
        node[]{hidden neuron};
    %ADDENDUM
    \foreach \n [count=\y from 0] in {1, 2, ..., 8} {
        \foreach \d [count=\x from 0] in {1, 2, ..., 6} {
            \draw
            (X0-Y0)+(.25 * \x,-0.25 * \y)node[draw=red,circle,inner sep=0.75mm](x\x-y\y){};
            \draw[->,blue!50!cyan,dashed]%Added some color
            (x\x-y\y) to [in=90, out=0] (out);
        }
    }
    \draw[<->] (X6-Y8) -- (X24-Y23);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @J Leon V.  Thanks for your solution.  I was trying to modify your solution to work at X0-Y0, however, I get the error, `No shape named 'X0-Y0' is known`.  How to get the selection to start at X0, Y0?  Thanks!

Comment: I have added additional information, sorry for the obscure code...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a possible way. The selection criteria are defined in `cond` in

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{(#1>20 && #1 <27 && #2 >11 && #2 <18 ? 1 :0)}
```

where `#1` and `#2` are the loop variables for the x and y coordinates. In this example, it tells Ti*k*Z to highlight the nodes for which the horizontal loop variable, `\X`, is between 20 and 27, and the vertical loop variable, `\Y` is between 11 and 18. You can adjust the highlighting condition to your needs. This code does two things. It highlights the respective nodes, and adds it to the list of connected nodes that get looped over in a second `\foreach` loop.

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    cond/.code 2 args={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{(#1>20 && #1 <27 && #2 >11 && #2 <18 ? 1 :0)}
    \ifnum\itest=1
     \ifcsname lstMyNodes\endcsname
      \xdef\lstMyNodes{\lstMyNodes,c-#1-#2}
     \else
      \xdef\lstMyNodes{c-#1-#2}
     \fi
     \tikzset{thick}
    \fi},circ/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2mm}]
 %  
 \path[local bounding box=input] foreach \Y in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
        foreach \X in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
         (.25 * \X - 2, -0.25 * \Y + 2) node[circ,cond={\X}{\Y}](c-\X-\Y){}}};
 \path  (8, -0.25 * 14 + 2)node[circ,label=above:hidden neuron](c-0-0){}
 (input.north) node[above]{input neurons};
 \path[latex-] foreach \X in \lstMyNodes
    {(c-0-0) edge (\X)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: added an arrow head.

You can change the condition to become a circle region.

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    cond/.code 2 args={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{(pow(#1-22.5,2)/25+pow(#2-14.5,2)/25 < 1 ? 1 :0)}
    \ifnum\itest=1
     \ifcsname lstMyNodes\endcsname
      \xdef\lstMyNodes{\lstMyNodes,c-#1-#2}
     \else
      \xdef\lstMyNodes{c-#1-#2}
     \fi
     \tikzset{thick}
    \fi},circ/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2mm}]
 %  
 \path[local bounding box=input] foreach \Y in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
        foreach \X in {1, 2, ..., 28} {
         (.25 * \X - 2, -0.25 * \Y + 2) node[circ,cond={\X}{\Y}](c-\X-\Y){}}};
 \path  (8, -0.25 * 14 + 2)node[circ,label={[yshift=1ex]above:hidden neuron}](c-0-0){}
 (input.north) node[above]{input neurons};
 \path[latex-] foreach \X in \lstMyNodes
    {(c-0-0) edge (\X)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]